# tabbed google maps, showing first instead of second map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

As the title says...the second map should be SATELLITE view, but it is showing the first map, why ?

Here is my CSS, JS and HTML

```css
#map-canvas, #map-canvas-2{width:90%; height:400px;}
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #32c896;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #238b68;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
    background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
    display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- and the JS and HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = $(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
            $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
 var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapCanvas2 = document.getElementById('map-canvas-2');
 var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.727201, -73.908737),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
    var mapOptions2 = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.727201, -73.908737),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas2, mapOptions2)
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>


<ul id="tabs">
 <li class="active">first</li>
 <li>second</li>
</ul>
<ul id="tab">
 <li class="active">
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div id="map-canvas-2"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your tabs. You only see the first tab. Also the `map2` variable is in another scope, so you get an error if you click on a tab button.

Comment: As graubnla indicated: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map2 is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the posted code snippet I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map2 is not defined`

1. To fix the javascript error make map2 global.
2. To fix the display of the second tab, which is hidden when `initialize` is called, trigger the map resize event *after* the div has been made visible.

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      var tabNum = $(this).index();
      var nthChild = tabNum + 1;
      $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
      $("ul#tab li:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");
      google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
      // reset the map center once the map has the correct size
      map2.setCenter(mapOptions2.center);
    }

  });
});
// make map2 global
var map2;
var mapOptions2;

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapCanvas2 = document.getElementById('map-canvas-2');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.727201, -73.908737),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  mapOptions2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.727201, -73.908737),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map
  });
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas2, mapOptions2);
  var m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions2.center,
    map: map2
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas,
#map-canvas-2 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
}
ul#tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul#tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #32c896;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #238b68;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
  background-color: #238b68;
}
ul#tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
  display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- and the JS and HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li class="active">first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>
<ul id="tab">
  <li class="active">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="map-canvas-2"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```